# reading FAT12 image file in C

Tags: c, file, binary, filesystems

I have a FAT12 image file and I have to open it and read it. I would like to view this image file(directories/files with in) so I can have an idea of what outcomes I should be getting. Anyone know of a good software that would let me view this FAT12 image file? Also can someone guide towards the right directions when trying to read the content of this image file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of open source FAT filesystem implementations around.

One which I think has nice clear portable code, though there are bugs, particularly in FAT12 implementation, is http://www.larwe.com/zws/products/dosfs/index.html.

Comment: +1. I've been using Larwes implementation and I can also recommend that. Very easy and straightforward to use.

Which FAT12 bugs do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can just mount it using the loopback device.

Answer (score 0):

There is Segger files system called [emFile](http://www.segger.com/emfile.html). It is portable fs, i have emFile working on number of embedded operating system with minimal (almost none, a few simple function that need to be implemented for each os) development effort. It's [not expensive](http://www.segger.com/pricelist_emfile.html) as well,i mean if you doing something for fun you probably don't want to spend money at all , but for commercial use it's cheap.

Answer (score 0):

http://hachoir.org/wiki/hachoir-parser

HTH